# Sending Facebook Invitations & Tracking Invitation Codes

Tags: jquery, json, facebook, api, facebook-c#-sdk

This is a follow up to [Invite users to register at my site through Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955332/invite-users-to-register-at-my-site-through-facebook).

I'm still working within a prototype application for now. I managed to use the Javascript API to send out invitations, but I'm having problems parsing the response object. Here's my code:

```
<a href="#">Send Application Request</a>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : '193005690721590',
          status  : true,
          cookie  : true,
          xfbml   : true
        });
    };

    $('a').click(sendRequest);
    function sendRequest() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Invitation to the test application!',
            title: 'Send your friends an application request',
            data: 'someCode'
        },
        function (response) {
            if (response && response.request_ids) {
                var requests = response.request_ids.join(',');
                console.log(requests);
                console.log(response);
                var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Parse',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: obj,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.result === 'ok') {
                            alert("Everything went fine");
                            //top.location.href = '/Home/About';
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert('canceled');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

And here's the action method that is supposed to parse the object, but for now I just want to check out the schema of the object using the debugger:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Parse(JsonObject response)
    {
        //parse the response object 

        return Json(new {result = "ok"});
    }
```

But, unfortunately, the response JsonObject appears to be null!

So how do I get this to work?

On a side not, is it possible to use the Facebook C# SDK to do the Request dialog stuff instead of using the Javascript API?

Comment: why send json? send simple get string. the string will be like "123123,382871,12389123" - this is request ids. use split to add them to array and then add to database

Comment: @evgeniy.labusnkiy: Why do I need to them to the database? And how do I get to the value passed in the 'data' property. One thing that is really confusing me is that the code for the invite should be on my site, but what about the Facebook app itself? Should it be something completely separate from the website?